# Is there a good Kotlin example how to pass the chronometer value into an argument as string?

Tags: android, kotlin, time, arguments, chronometer

I have a working Chronomer in Kotlin Android app in a Fragment. When I click the pause or stop button I would like to be able to pass that stopped chronometer value into an argument, then display it elsewhere as example:1m30s.

Any tips where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Assume in your fragment, `chronometer` is variable name of `Chronomer`. When users click on pause/stop button, use this code to get the chronometer value.

```
// Regex for HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
val regex = "([0-1]?\\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\\d))?(?::([0-5]?\\d))?"

val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
val matcher = pattern.matcher(chronometer.text)
if (matcher.find()) {
    val isHHMMSSFormat = matcher.groupCount() == 4
    val chronometerValue = if (isHHMMSSFormat) {
        val hour = matcher.group(1).toInt()
        val minute = matcher.group(2).toInt()
        val second = matcher.group(3).toInt()
        "${hour}h${minute}m${second}s"
    } else {
        val minute = matcher.group(1).toInt()
        val second = matcher.group(2).toInt()
        "${minute}m${second}s"
    }

    // TODO: Pass the `chronometerValue` into argument
    //  or anything you want here
    Log.i("Chronometer Value", chronometerValue)
}
```